# Low signal on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop

Tags: wireless, 22.04

Couple of days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop [Acer Aspire E5-576] alongside with Windows 10. I have noticed that my WiFi signal is extremely low when using Ubuntu, compared to Windows. I have tried many methods to fix this: Turning off power management, updating and downgrading kernel versions and etc. (I'm currently using 5.15.0-47 generic) and many others

iwconfig (Router is right in front of the laptop):

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f1  no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"\xD9\x8A\xD9\x85 \xD8\xA7\xD9\x8A\xD8\xA8\xD8\xB3\xD9\x88\xD9\x85 \xD9\x87\xD9\x88 \xD9\x86\xD9\x85\xD9\x88\xD8\xB0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 66:7B:9D:70:C6:F5   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:93   Missed beacon:0
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  9
cmac                   16384  4
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_soc_skl           172032  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    61440  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          339968  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     77824  1
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   159744  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         163840  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
intel_tcc_cooling      16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_hda_core          110592  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
coretemp               24576  0
ath10k_pci             49152  0
ath10k_core           602112  1 ath10k_pci
btusb                  61440  0
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
mac80211             1253376  1 ath10k_core
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm_intel             372736  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
snd_pcm               143360  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
uvcvideo              106496  0
cfg80211              974848  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
btintel                40960  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
kvm                  1028096  1 kvm_intel
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
snd_rawmidi            49152  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             704512  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mei_hdcp               24576  0
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
snd_seq                77824  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
videodev              258048  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
nouveau              2306048  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
aesni_intel           376832  11
i915                 3104768  22
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    86016  3 drm_ttm_helper,i915,nouveau
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
drm_kms_helper        311296  2 i915,nouveau
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
rapl                   20480  0
acer_wmi               28672  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
rc_core                65536  1 cec
mei_me                 40960  1
snd                   106496  23 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
intel_pch_thermal      20480  0
joydev                 32768  0
input_leds             16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
serio_raw              20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei                   135168  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
acpi_pad              184320  0
acer_wireless          20480  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       122880  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             49152  0
ppdev                  24576  0
mtd                    77824  0
lp                     28672  0
drm                   622592  13 drm_kms_helper,drm_ttm_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
parport                69632  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
pstore_blk             16384  0
ramoops                32768  0
pstore_zone            32768  1 pstore_blk
efi_pstore             16384  0
reed_solomon           28672  1 ramoops
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                49152  2
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         32768  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
psmouse               176128  0
r8168                 552960  0
i2c_i801               36864  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
rtsx_pci              106496  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
intel_lpss_pci         24576  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
ahci                   45056  2
libahci                45056  1 ahci
xhci_pci               24576  0
idma64                 20480  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
video                  61440  3 acer_wmi,i915,nouveau
wmi                    32768  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,acer_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Comment: I suggest upgrading the system firmware to the latest available version. It is not by any means guaranteed to help, but can't hurt unless you do it wrong.

Comment: I have same problem, wifi router is 50cm from my laptop on the table. wavemon shows link quality 100% (70/70) and signal level is yellow bar with -35dBm, with sometime dropping to -40 and turning red. I thought it's router setting at first so I tried all combinations, N, B, G, mixed, 20Hz, 40Hz... nothing helps, same result. While same router works great with other wifi devices. By any chance you found solution for this? p.s. pinging router sometimes throws as high as 130ms...while on average is like 7-8ms.